# Write image to webpage with python 3

Tags: python, image

I have currently got this code set up:

```
    import time
    import http.server
    import socketserver
    import mimetypes
    import os

    HOST_NAME = 'localhost'
    PORT = 8000


    def load(self):
        with open(self, 'r') as self:
        self = self.read()
        return self.encode('UTF-8')



    class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_HEAD(self):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            def do_GET(self):
                    if self.path == "/":
                        self.send_response(200)
                        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
                        self.end_headers()
                        self.wfile.write(load('index.html'))
                    if self.path.endswith('.css'):
                        self.send_response(200)
                        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/css")
                        self.end_headers()
                        dest = self.path.replace("/", "")
                        self.wfile.write(load(dest))
                    if self.path == "/bg.jpg":
                        self.send_response(200)
                        self.send_header("Content-type", "image/jpeg")
                        self.end_headers()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyHandler)
        print(time.asctime(), "Server Starts - %s:%s" % ("", PORT))
        try:
            httpd.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        httpd.server_close()
        print(time.asctime(), "Server Stops - %s:%s" % ("", PORT))
```

My webpage seems to be working and I get my index.html and css loaded when I open up my webpage, however the image is not coming through, has anyone got any idea why?

Comment: At least part of your problem is, as written, your `do_GET` is defined inside your `do_HEAD` method and is not a method of the handler class.  That being the case your `do_GET` will never be called.  It's possible the HTML is being loaded from some other path.

Comment: Where do you actually send your imge. You only seem to send the headers....

Comment: Unrelatedly, assuming your indentation problems are just a transcription error, it looks like your `self.path == 'bg.jpg'` clause does not actually send the file content at all.

Comment: Its just this weird stackoverflow codinf thing, idention is fine in my file.

Comment: I did t write anything in == 'bg.jpg' because all my previous tries failds :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send an image over HTTP, just write the image data directly to the socket, like for any other type of file. You can't use your `load()` function for this, since that encodes the text as UTF-8. Instead, you should open the file with mode `rb` or similar, read a `bytes` from that filehandle, then write it directly to `self.wfile` in the HTTP handler.

Comment: thank you for your help, but I do not exactly get what you mean with 'read a bytes', do you have an example? Thanks in advance!